# Excel Multiple IF/AND/OR conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Pretty simple questions but i couldn't find out how it works and i've search almost a week for an answer now.

Example:

/ One Number is above 0 and one below

- A1: 1
- B1: -1

/ Both Numbers are below 0

- A1: -1
- B1: -2

/ Both Numbers are above 0

- A1: 9
- B1: 2

So i want to check 3 or 4 things.

- A1 and B1 are below 0 = return "below"
- A1 and B1 are === 0 or above 0 return "above"
- A1 is below 0 and B1 is above 0 return "above and below"
- A1 is above 0 and B1 is below 0  return "above and below"

Comment: So far i've this one but the last 2 checks are not working, if one number is above and one is below 0

=IF(AND(B25<0,C25<0),"both below",IF(AND(B25>=0,C25>=0),"both above",IF(AND(B25<0,C25>=0,"above and below",IF(B25>=0,C25<0,"above and below")))))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    =CHOOSE(1+(B25<0)+(C25<0), "both above", "above and below", "both below")
```

I used `B25` and `C25` because from your comment I saw that you want to reference these cells.

If you want to distinguish cases "below and above" from "above and below", use this:

```
=IF(AND(B25<0,C25<0),"both below", IF(B25<0,"below and above",
     IF(C25<0,"above and below","both above")))
```

p.s.

Your formula (that you posted in the comment) was almost correct but missed some parentheses. It could be fixed like this:

```
=IF(AND(B25<0,C25<0),"both below",
   IF(AND(B25>=0,C25>=0),"both above",
     IF(AND(B25<0,C25>=0),"below and above",
       IF(AND(B25>=0,C25<0),"above and below"))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider:

```
=IF(MIN(A1,B1)>0,"above",IF(MAX(A1,B1)<0,"below","above and below"))
```

This assumes that neither **A1** nor **B1** will be exactly zero.

Comment: It is perfect it only needs `>=0` instead of `>0` and it can take care of the `0` case as specified by OP :)

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(AND(A1<0,B1<0),
"below",
  IF(AND(A1>=0,B1>=0),
"above",
  IF(AND(A1<0,B1>0),
"below and above",
   IF(AND(A1>0,B1<0),
"above and below",
""
   )
   )
   )
)
```